# (Commutative) Algebras in $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$

Tags: model-categories, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, dg-categories

Suppose $k$ is a fixed commutative ring, and let $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$ denote the category of $k$-linear dg-categories. We will equip $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$ with the Morita model structure (see theorem 2.27 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.4303.pdf) or theorem 2.22 [here](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Edcisinsk/Non-connective-K-theory.pdf)). The category $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$ admits a symmetric monoidal structure, as defined in section 4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408337.pdf).

$\mathsf{dgCat}_k$ equipped with this symmetric monoidal structure is not a monoidal model category. As such, we cannot apply results of [Schwede-Shipley](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801082.pdf) or [White](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/white-monoids.pdf) to produce a model category structure on algebra objects in $\mathsf{dgCat}_k.$

However, a result of Cohn says that the underlying $\infty$-category of $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$ localized at the Morita equivalences is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of small idempotent-complete $k$-linear stable $\infty$-categories. The latter category does (I believe) have a symmetric monoidal structure induced by the Lurie tensor product of stable $\infty$-categories (this is claimed, for example, in section 10.4 [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/HA.pdf)). This implies the existence of a sensible category of commutative algebras in the $\infty$-category of dg-categories.

My question is, **how can we talk about such things at the level of model categories?** I would like to be able to talk about the homotopy pushout of a diagram of commutative (or maybe $E_\infty$) algebras in $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$, but the standard results do not guarantee that the category of such objects would admit a model structure. (I want to construct a relative derived tensor product of commutative algebras in dg-categories, and I want the result to retain the algebra structure, instead of only having a module structure.) Given the equivalence of $\infty$-categories above, it seems that there may be some reasonable way to talk about such things at the model-category level. Or am I asking for too much?

**More generally, is there any "standard" way of discussing derived/homotopy coherent notions of algebras in a symmetric monoidal category which is also a model category (but which is not a monoidal model category)?**

Comment: The usual workaround for questions like this is to use the model category of (symmetric) dg multicategories, a.k.a. coloured dg operads. That forms a much larger category than monoidal dg categories, and that flexibility allows e.g. cofibrant replacement.

Comment: @JonPridham Thanks for this! Are there any "standard" places where one might learn the basics about these things and their homotopy theory, or any references where they're used to circumvent issues similar to the ones I mentioned in the question?

Comment: For model structures, Marcy Robertson's 2008 thesis covers a lot of ground. There's also a paper by Stanculescu. I can't remember where I first read to use the embedding of monoidal categories in multicategories, it's so ingrained.

Comment: I like Jon Pridham's suggestion. For some reason, names that jump into my head reading that are Elmendorf and also Niles Johnson and Donald Yau. Another option might be to weaken the model category axioms. If the issue has to do with the cofibrations and the monoidal product, then maybe a right semi-model structure would still have its notion of homotopy coherent monoidal product. Or one of Simon Henry's weak model structures (if he has a notion of what it means for one to be monoidal). Maybe focusing on only the Brown category of fibrant objects inside the model structure. Just brainstorming.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions! @JonPridham, do you have any idea where I might access Marcy Robertson's thesis? I haven't been able to track it down.

Comment: @Stahl I think this might be in the papers 'Spaces of operad structures' and 'The homotopy theory of simplicially enriched multicategories' , or it seems to match some of what Jon Pridham might be referencing.